# How to use Alamofire + Searchbar?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know much about iOS because it's my first time dealing with it.

So I might not have enough explanation.

I'm sorry about that.

I would like to use alamofire and Searchbar.

So I'm applying it to various tutorials.

But now I'm running into an error.

It's my code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var filteredData: [String]!
    var arr_id = [String]()
    var arr_name = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.mytableview.delegate = self
        self.mytableview.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = []
        
        let myapiUrl = "http://myurl/test/name.php?name=" + searchText
        
        AF.request(myapiUrl, method: .get).responseJSON { (myresponse) in
            switch myresponse.result {
            case .success:
                print(myresponse.result)
                
                let myresult = try? JSON(data: myresponse.data!)
                print(myresult!)
                
                let resultArray = myresult!
                
                self.arr_id.removeAll()
                self.arr_name.removeAll()
                
                for i in resultArray.arrayValue {
                    let id = i["id"].stringValue
                    self.arr_id.append(id)
                    
                    let name = i["name"].stringValue
                    self.arr_name.append(name)
                }
                self.mytableview.reloadData()
                break
                
            case .failure:
                print(myresponse.error!)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error in the code.

However, when I run it, the AppDelegate will get an error.

`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

And it's error log.

```
2020-10-25 14:57:13.668841+0900 Foodin[5941:314426] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a042d7 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 619
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a13aca -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a14277 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ca3cf -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 150
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480c9ac0 -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 232
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480cab43 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 362
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff480ddef1 -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482e9431 -[UIWindowScene _makeKeyAndVisibleIfNeeded] + 202
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4761d445 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1405
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4808f170 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1018
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4808f4b2 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 304
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bfa7f5 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365d6165 -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 442
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc4d8 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365e0c45 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc169 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106eb7d48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106ebacb9 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662237e __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662206c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662257b -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4471 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd439c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3bcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce87f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    31  Foodin                              0x0000000105c9005b main + 75
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have some problems before Alamofire and SearchBar issue. Main problem is tableview inheritance..

Try to change your Table View class to UITableView from Storyboard or make subclass of your `UITableViewController` to `UiViewController`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An `UITableViewController` has a predefined `tableView` property.

Delete the `IBOutlet` and use the `tableView` property instead.

Notes:

- Delete the `break` keywords in the `switch` expression. They are not needed in Swift.
- Loading (apparently) the same data in `textDidChange` again and again is unnecessarily inefficient. Load the data once and **filter** it.
- Multiple arrays as data source is a horrible practice. You should look for better tutorials. Create a custom struct.
- Drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of the `Codable` protocol.
- Never declare a property representing an array as implicit unwrapped optional. Declare it as non-optional empty array.
- Don’t use those ugly *snake_cased* variable names. The Swift convention is *lowerCamelCase*.
- Never ignore potential errors with `try?` - especially during development - and never force unwrap optionals which can be `nil`.

Comment: - plus using camelCase and meaningful property names should be more Swifty rather than such as expression arr_name..

Comment: thanks for your golden notes as well for community.